# Font Awesome wp_enqueue_style

Tags: css, child-theme

I have been trying to get the same code I have on my old server to work on my new server. This is the code I have thus far:

```
function enqueue_load_fa() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'load-fa', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css' );
}
```

The issue I am having is that on my test site http://thedroidgamer.info/2018/11/25/hello-world/ it is not working but on my other one it is. See screenshot below: 
https://scrnshot.app/DfNnwwV3ba3.png

Both servers have the same exact coding. I have tried 3 servers in all and only one of them has worked, with the same code. I am not understanding why it's not being accepted at all.

Comment: That function isn't going to do anything unless you hook it with `add_action()`. Have you done that?

Comment: I have this underneath that:

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'enqueue_load_fa' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

Comment: Some thing to note that the css is not added to your webpage ..you can check that with developer tools on your web page ..means you have made some mistake in coding..post your complete code you might have made a typo some where

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
function enqueue_load_fa() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'load-fa', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_load_fa');
```

Comment: Why should this fix anything? Could you elaborate and explain your answer?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż i think `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'enqueue_load_fa' )` this was used by @thedroidgamer

Comment: The first half of my code
`<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'twentynineteen-style'; // This is 'twentynineteen-style' for the Twenty Nineteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}`

Comment: The second half: 
`function enqueue_load_fa() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'load-fa', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_load_fa' );
?>`

Comment: I did notice that css is not loading, noticed that the theme being used was not called properly. it is working now -.- So sorry guys!

Comment: @thedroidgamer okay cheers :)

Comment: Latheesh - you should edit your answer to explain in the answer why this would be the answer (specifically - the addition of add_action() that thedroidgamer did not use). Always give a description of "why" with the "what" and "how". It makes a better answer.